# Removing the Dot-Patterns Like Noise

Tags: image-processing, denoising

I am dealing with an image restoration problem with noisy measurement. I use the classical total variation norm to remove the noise, specifically, the TV-$L_2$ problem. I used the famous Lena image for testing (size $256\times 256)$.

[image]

The result is attached below:

[image]

As can be seen, there are some dot-patterns like noise still existing in the denoise image. When I increase the coefficient for TV norm, the whole image becomes blurred and details are lost.

Could anyone tell me how to deal with these local non-uniform noise patterns? It seems that they are bandpass patterns.

---

**P.S.** I am dealing with an image reconstruction problem named phase retrieval with noisy measurements. The measurements are collected via practical devices. I use the TV norm as the regularization term to improve the reconstruction performance. However, the non-uniform artifacts appear in the reconstructed image (see above). So are there some denoising algorithms that could deal with this situation? I adopt an optimization framework that can treat the proximal operator as a denoising problem. So I just focus on the denoising problem.

Comment: Are you adding noise to the image or trying to denoise it as is?

Comment: @Royi The measurement is not from the simulation but from the practical device. I assume that the Poisson noise, Gaussian noise, and saturation situation exist.

Comment: @Royi Specifically, I deal with the problem named phase retrieval. I collected the Fourier intensity measurements and reconstruct the original image. The measurement is acquired by the CMOS camera.

Comment: Are you after a TV Denoising with less artifacts?

Comment: @Royi Hi, I use TV denoising, the whole image becomes smoother (sharp details lost) although with less dot-like patterns.

Comment: @Royi The whole image becomes quite smooth.

Comment: This is what I am asking, are you after a TV Denoising just without the artifacts?

Comment: @Royi I am not sure I got your point. Do you mean that did I directly feed the noiseless measurement to the stated algorithm? If so, the answer is yes, I got the perfect reconstuction.

Comment: No, I mean are you after a TV Denoising without the pattern? There are many variants of TV Denoising. Some of tries to mitigate the phenomenon you see.

Comment: @Royi I am a bit confused, what do you mean by *'after'*? I edited the problem and added the supplementary comments. I used the TV norm as regularization and try to reconstruct the image as the original one (first image) but I got the second image. So I think this is related to TV denoising algorithm, and I hope to use better denoising algorithm. I adopt this method: https://epfl-lts2.github.io/unlocbox-html/doc/prox/prox_tv.html

Comment: @Royi The objective is to remove the artifacts (patterns) and obtain the clean image with an appropriate algorithm. Thanks

Comment: You wrote: I use the classical total variation norm to remove the noise, specifically, the TV-L2 problem. So you use TV for denoising. As I wrote there are many variations of TV. Are you after a variation with less blocky artifact?

Comment: @Royi Hi, currently I just use Isotropic TV for denoising, so I would try Anisotropic TV. Would you have other suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your noise model is similar to the noise model of SAR which is basically a phase reconstruction. You may look at this survey: [Image denoising and despeckling methods for SAR images to improve image enhancement performance: a survey](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11042-021-10871-7).

Comment: A $40 article? It better be good!